# Combining 2 dataframes without a common joiner

Tags: python, pandas

I have df1 with all item names only and df2 with 2 columns of due date and items. How do I combine them so it will result in one dataframe with the due date as the row names and and keep the item names.

df1 looks like this

```
1  Index |   DueDate     

2.   0   |  1/1/2018   
3.   1   |  1/2/2018   
4.   2   |  1/2/2018      
5.   3   |  1/4/2018    
6.   4   |  1/5/2018   
7.   5   |  1/5/2018
```

df2 looks like

```
1.   Index   |   Item1   |   Item2   |   Item 3   |    Item 4
```

and so on. I want to make the due date the row names of df2 like follows:

```
1. DueDate     Item1       |   Item2   |     Item3     |   Item4
2. 1/1/2018     
3. 1/2/2018
4. 1/3/2018
5. 1/4/2018
6. 1/5/2018
```

I have tired tried appending it with will result in similar result but it uses the due date column just as another column added not as a row name.

Comment: you can try: `pd.crosstab(index=df1['DueDate'], columns=df1['items'])`

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following:

```
# create a pivot
df = pd.crosstab(index=df1['DueDate'], columns=df1['items']).astype(str)

# replace all values with a blank
df = df.replace(regex=r'.*', value='')

items            item1      item3      item4         item4    
DueDate                                                       
1/1/2018                                                      
1/2/2018                                                      
1/4/2018                                                      
1/5/2018
```